# For loop isn't returning -1 when I want it to as per the conditions

Tags: java

The issue is that when an integer lesser than or equals to 0 is passed as a parameter for 'end', and when 'end' is lesser than 'start' it doesn't return -1.

```
    public static boolean isOdd (int number)
    {
        if (number < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (number % 2 != 0 )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is method to test the parameter 'start' and 'end'

```
    public static int sumOdd (int start, int end)
    {
        
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = start; i<=end; i++)
        {
            if ((start<=0) || (end<=0) || (end<start))
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (isOdd(i))
                {
                    sum+=i;
                }   
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: Your loop will loop while `i<=end` where `i` is initialized as `start`. How many iterations do you think it will take for `i<=end` to become false when `start` is a larger value than `end`?

Comment: Glad to help :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your `for` loop.

You instructed the loop to run when `i` was smaller or equal to `end`. That's sounds good on paper, but you do realize that this statement

```
if ((start<=0) || (end<=0) || (end<start))
```

will never be run (in the case that `end` is larger than `start`), since `i` is `start`, and if `end` is bigger than `start`, it is therefore bigger than `i`, which wouldn't satisfy your previous defined condition in the for loop, `i is smaller or equal to end`. Therefore, the `for` loop will never run.

You should be doing:

```
public static int sumOdd(int start, int end) {
        int sum = 0;
        if ((start <= 0) || (end <= 0) || (end < start)) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
                if (isOdd(i)) {
                    sum += i;
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }
    }
```

**Test Run**

`sumOdd(1, 0)` returns `-1`

`sumOdd(1, 3)` returns `4`